# webpack.externals relative path causes Unexpected token

Tags: typescript, webpack, webpack-4

when I add a relative path to `webpack.externals` array, the output file contains: `module.exports = ../path;` which causes the error: Unexpected token.

```
//webpack.config.js
{
 externals: ['../path']
}
```

```
//input.ts
import something from '../path';
```

```
//output.js
module.exports = ../path;
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed by using a function instead of an object

```
{
 externals:[  
   function(..){
     //checking
     return callback(null, "commonjs path")
   }
 ]
}
```